# Deleting elements from list and rows from numpy array when condition holds in Python

Tags: python, numpy, nlp, delete-row, del

I'm writing an algorithm in order to classify the tweets in my dataset as positive/negative and I want to test the accuracy of it. In order to do this and find the best possible solution I want to have a baseline (using classical ML algorithms). After preprocessing the tweets, inspired by the related work, I explored firstly with the Bag-of-Words model and I managed to successfully run the code and calculate the accuracy and the Fscore. After some text preprocessing and splitting the dataset into the train set and the test set:

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test1, y_train, y_test1 = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.11, random_state = 0)
```

I want to be able to eliminate all the tweets labeled as negative from the test set (keeping only the positive ones) and calculate the precision, recall, and Fscore of the algorithm (and afterwards do the same thing for the tweets labeled as positive). I tried doing it like this:

```
finRow = len(X_test1) 
finCol = len(X_test1[0])

for o in range(0, finrow):
    if y_test1[o]== 1:
       del y_test1[o]
       X_test1 = np.delete(X_test1, o, axis=0)
```

but I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-4-5ed18876a8b5>", line 2, in <module>
if y_test1[o]== 1:

IndexError: list index out of range
```

*X_test1* contains the tweets and it's of size 1102 x 564 and *y_test1* contains zeros and ones (the tweet is positive or negative) and has a size of 1102. The error appears at the 774th iteration, when the length of *y_test1* decreases from 1102 to 774.

Now, I tried doing it like this also:

```
a = 1
for o in range(0, finrow):
    if (y_test1[o] == 1 and o <= finrow - a):
       del y_test1[o]
       a = a + 1
       X_test1 = np.delete(X_test1, o, axis=0)
```

but I still get the same error and I don't know if this is the best approach of deleting the rows of the matrix and the elements of the list because when I'm checking the values of *y_test1* I still have some (a few, not all - as in the beginning) of the elements that were supposed to be deleted.

I'm kind of new at this, and I have no idea where my mistake is.

Comment: When you `del` a list its size changes, and indexes get messed up.  If you must iterate through a list and `del` items start at the end and work toward the start..  Experiment with small lists interactively if you can't picture what's happening.

Comment: Thank you for the tip! Will use it in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to have a look at the function `classification_report` in scikit-learn.

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html

It's the easiest way to compute Precision/Recall and F1 for each class.

You just need to pass two arrays, first with the true predictions and the second with the predictions from your classifier, e.g.:

```
predictions = your_clf.predict(X_test1)
classification_report(y_test1, prediction)
```

Comment: Thank you! It does exactly what I wanted and even more. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

`y_test == 0` creates an array of booleans that can be used to filter out rows from `y_test` and `x_test`.

```
positive_indexes = y_test == 0
y_test_positive = y_test[positive_indexes]
x_test_positive = x_test[positive_indexes]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [328]: alist = list(range(10))
In [329]: alist
Out[329]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Removing items from a list changes the indices of the subsequent items.

```
In [330]: del alist[7]          # removes the 7
In [331]: alist
Out[331]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9]
In [332]: del alist[8]          # removes the 9, not the 8       
In [333]: alist
Out[333]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8]
In [334]: del alist[8]          # with only 8 items left, error
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Removing items starting with end preserves the indices of remaining items:

```
In [335]: alist = list(range(10))
In [336]: del alist[9]
In [337]: del alist[8]
In [338]: del alist[7]
In [339]: del alist[6]
In [340]: alist
Out[340]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```